# Can anyone tell me what this coin was used for, an approximate date and possibly what it’s worth?

Tags: numismatics

It says 'Play coins of the world' with a 50 in the center on one side and on the other side it says Reis Brazil.

[image: front and pack of brown coin]

Comment: What is it made of?  "Play coins of the word" sounds like a game token.

Comment: Yeah I’m positive it’s a game token as well. It seems to be made of zink. I found it in an old house that was built in the late 1800s and More than anything I’m just kind of cerious about when it was made

Comment: réis (with "é") is the plural of real, the currency unit. As the currency unit was too small, the plural was almost always used. And this means that your play coin is older than 1942, when the real was abandoned

Comment: Unless the colour balance of the photo is off, it doesn't look like zinc: zinc is silver-coloured.

Comment: The photo makes it seem to be a copper colour although it is a silver colour. It’s a super light metal. I could bend it with my fingers if I tried.

Answer (score 35):

Not a Game Token.  It's play money for children from Topps and it is collectable.

[image]

That's a **Topps 1949 Play Coins of the World piece**.  Tops issued 24 countries,  with values 5, 10, 25, 50 or 100; in 1948 and 49.
**[Topps Archive](http://toppsarchives.blogspot.com/2011/04/drastic-plastic-surgery.html)**

[image]

They are collectable. I found them going on **[eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Topps-Play-Coins-of-the-World-metalized-Token-Coin-RUSSIA-RUBLE-100/273409147426?hash=item3fa8748222:g:uVQAAOSwtO5XInQC)** for about $9.95 per coin.  Originally they sold for 10 cents for a pack of 5 and a stick of gum.

The 72 "metal coins" in the series came with Play Money Pops should be categorized as a 1950 issue.

There was also a run in the 1960's which are also collectable.  They go for about $3 per coin on [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1960S-TOPPS-NEW-COINS-OF-THE-WORLD-PERU-PLAY-MONEY/183336510252?hash=item2aafb5232c:g:KOwAAOSwn1RXIrhS:sc:USPSFirstClass!20176!US!-1)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! i just figured it was a game token of some sort.

Comment: The design doesn't seem to match any 50 réis coin that can be found in the internet. Considering the the "russian" coin even uses latin alphabet, this is perhaps unsurprising.

Comment: @LuísHenrique  The back side with the globe is spot on for the original coin, which can be found on the Topps site.  I added another picture to the bottom of my answer.   One of the boxes of the coins has a drawn image of the Brazilian coin I boxed with blue, bottom left.  It also is spot on for the coin, but it's just a drawn coin.

Comment: @JMS - I'm sorry, I can't find the original coin in Topps site. Is there another link that I should follow?

Comment: It would be nice if this answer was ticked as the best answer.